# Raise statements: Why does my block of code return an empty list instead of executing my "raise" statement?

Tags: python-3.x, raise

Firstly, I apologise if my question comes across as stupid or if there are any errors in my post - This is my second post, and I am still finding it difficult how to ask appropriate questions on this platform.

Secondly, I have tried to look up the logic behind the "raise" statement using the examples from the Python Docs website (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) and another post on Stackoverflow ([Raise statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703495/raise-statement)) but I still cannot wrap my head around this "raise" statement.

I am trying to answer the following question from the Ebook **Introduction to computation and programming using Python**: "Implement a function that satisfies the specification." (See function specification below).

```
def findAnEven(L):
    """
    ASSUMES: L is a list of integers 
    RETURNS: the first even number in L
    Raises ValueError if L does not contain an even number
    """
```

---

Below is my attempt to solve this question:

---

```
def findAnEven(L):
    """
    ASSUMES: L is a list of integers
    RETURNS: the first even number in L
    Raises ValueError if L does not contain an even number
    """
    try:
        evenNumbers = []
        for i in L:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                evenNumbers.append(i)
                break
        return(evenNumbers)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("ValueError exception thrown")
findAnEven([1,2,3,4]) # RETURNS: [2]
findAnEven([1,1,1,1]) # RETURNS: [] - THIS SHOULD EXECUTE RAISE STATEMENT, NOT RETURN AN EMPTY LIST
```

I am trying to understand why my block of code is only returning an empty list, instead of executing my "raise" statement?

If anyone can explain (in layman terms) why my block of code is returning an empty list to the last function call (i.e., findAnEven([1,1,1,1]) instead of executing my "raise" statement, I would be very grateful - Again apologies for the stupid question!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. I was trying to answer the following specification, as mentioned above in my post:

def findAnEven(L):
    """
    ASSUMES: L is a list of integers 
    RETURNS: the first even number in L
    Raises ValueError if L does not contain an even number
    """

The chapter in the Python ebook was related to "Exceptions" and the specific exercise related to "raising a ValueError", if L (which is supposed to be a list) does not contain an even number. 
I was trying to answer the question in the ebook with what I had learnt so far but finding it tricky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    evenNumbers = []
    for i in L:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            evenNumbers.append(i)
            break
    return(evenNumbers)
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("ValueError exception thrown")
```

The code in the `except` block will never be executed since no line in the `try` block can ever raise a `ValueError`. In case there are no even numbers in `L`, the `if` is never `True` and `return(evenNumbers)` just returns the empty `evenNumbers` list.

If you want to raise an exception instead of returning an empty list, do that explicitly.
I also took the liberty to make your code more pythonic and succinct.
Once it finds the first even number it will return a list that contains it.
If the `return` statement is never hit, that means no even number was found, so we raise `ValueError` with a clear message.

```
def find_an_even(L):
    """
    ASSUMES: L is a list of integers
    RETURNS: the first even number in L
    Raises ValueError if L does not contain an even number
    """
    
    for n in L:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return [n]
            # or just 'return n' if you want to return the number not within a list
    raise ValueError("No even numbers in L")
```

Comment: Hi DeepSpace, thank you for your response and apologies for the late reply, I was trying to understand what you had written before replying. It appears that I had not asked a specific enough question but you still managed to understand what I was trying to achieve with your response -  

"If you want to raise an exception instead of returning an empty list, do that explicitly."

This was exactly what I was trying to achieve but was failing and producing an empty list instead. Thank you for the explanation and your code example to clarify, I also appreciate the "Pythonic" refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

First off, there are no stupid questions! Everyone learns at their own pace.

Python's `raise` is part of a series of Error related keywords in Python (see full list [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)). The most important ones you should know are `try`, `except`, and `raise`. I'll explain each of them here:

- `try` is always paired with `except`, as you did here. What happens is that whatever is *"in scope"* for the `try` will execute just like any normal block of code would. However, if something bad happens (i.e your code makes a bad assumption or something breaks) and a `ValueError` is raised, the script does **not** immediately terminate or stop executing - instead, it "bubbles up" that error to the `except` clause immediately below, and allows you to handle it instead, just as you did here. **However, the stuff in the except clause only gets executed if a `ValueError` is ACTUALLY RAISED while executing the `try` clause**. If the code in the `try` clause executes without any issues, then the `except` clause's code *is never executed* - it is skipped entirely.
- Once the issue is bubbled up to the `except` clause, you can have it print something or do whatever you want, then force it to actually halt execution by using the `raise` keyword, which artificially creates an Error inside your Error handler (i.e the `except` clause).

In your example, a `ValueError` never gets raised anywhere (since your code does not break), so the `except` clause's code is never called! I think you're conflating an "Error" with something just being `False`. In your example, `findAnEven([1,1,1,1])` executes perfectly - it returns an empty list, since there are indeed no even numbers in the list you passed. The fact that there are no even numbers is not an Error - it's just a fact about your inputted list.

Comment: Hi @victor__von__doom, thanks for your response and apologies for the late reply. Like Deepspace's comments before yours, I was just trying to fully understand what has been suggested before replying. Your points are really insightful and thanks for the "bubbles up" analogy, it is an interesting way to think about the except clause.